# Sitecore|WFFM| Custom Error Message with details| on Same Page with Form

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a Web Form for Marketer set up done for one of my Pages.

I have **Custom Submit  Action** written for it as shown below in the code snippet -

```cs
public class **CustomFormSubmit : ISaveAction**
{
    public void Execute(ID formid, AdaptedResultList fields, params object[] data)
    {

        try
        {
           **//var returnValue=  Custom Logic  to save form data // returns true or false** 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex.Message + ":" + builder, ExceptionCategory.Error);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In my above **Web form - Success Mode is - SuccessMode/Redirect and I have a success Page configured for it.**

My requirement in above scenario is to keep user on the same Page(with Form)  if returnValue is false . (as shown in above code snippet)

Can anyone Please guide me in the above scenario  as - how to keep user on the same Page with values filled in the form so that user can submit it again.
Product Details -  7.2 rev. 141226 , Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev.140117

To add **further details -**
I am not sure how can I go back to my page instead of the redirection in case if return is false in the above code snippet.
As soon the submit button is clicked the above function- Execute-  gets called.
**How do I go back to the Page - Do I need to override any function or customize something.**

If **any exception comes** while saving data- then the control goes back to the same Page with all values filled by user retained -with the **Save Action Failed Message which is configured in Sitecore** .
**So my requirement will be** to go to to the form as happening in case of Exception when false comes as return value while saving data and to put customised Error Messages which might change each time, so not statically configured ,rather a dynamic one.
Thanks!
Saurabh

Comment: For clarity, the Logic that returns true or false, it only tries to save the data it does not validate it in someway?

Comment: Hi @JonathanRobbins
Actually Custom Data Validation I have written before and it works to keep the user in same Page of there is any issue with Data user enters.
In my scenario I try to save the data through an API call and if if API call returns true/SuccessI want user to be re-directed to Success Page and if API call returns False I want user to be in the same Page with Web Form data filled.

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer your additional edit

Comment: Hi @JonathanRobbins -Thanks -Few more additional inputs required.
1) Once we throw the Exception - Error message displayed is as below in bottom of the Page - 
! We have found an error
"and My Custom Error Message which I Pass while i throw the Exception"
-> How can we change the styling/css for this error message.Currently its shown in bottom of the Page. I would like to show it in Page top.Also the first line- "! We have found an error" - is something which is coming by default - How can this message  be configured.

Comment: 2) Also for patching  FormSubmitFailedArgs and SubmitFailedArgs I have update my forms.config as shown  below in <errorSubmit> section as - 
<processor type="ProjectName.Framework.CMS.Pipelines.FormSubmitFailedArgs, ProjectName.Framework.CMS"/> . Is it the correct place for patching the FormSubmitFailedArgs.?? <errorSubmit> section is below my <successAction> section.
<errorSubmit>
 <processor type="ProjectName.Framework.CMS.Pipelines.FormSubmitFailedArgs, ProjectName.Framework.CMS"/>
 <processor type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormSubmit.FormatMessage, Sitecore.Forms.Core"/>
</errorSubmit>

Comment: I've updated my answer again to answer both of your new questions. It'll get you 90% of the way there - don't forget to vote on answers and mark as Answered.

Comment: Hi @JonathanRobbins,

Considering the above scenario - Before I throw Exception - I want to save some GUID value which I have in my public void Execute() method . 
Later when exception is thrown and user resubmits the Form I want to access the previously saved GUID value and write some logic based on it.
So What would be the best way to save some value and then throw Exception and once form is re- submitted again, We would need to access the saved value in case of my above mentioned scenario.
Thanks!
Saurabh

Comment: Hi @JonathanRobbins
I  have a similiar kind of requirement with little tweaks in it in terms of showing Excpetion Message in the Form from the Custom Upload File control @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515195/sitecore-wffm-exception-message-from-file-upload-to-be-displayed-on-page
Can you Please have a look at this link.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option will be to redirect to the original page with the Form on.

Enable your form to populate the fields via Query String using the `ReadQueryString` property, via Presentation Details of the Form Renderer:

[image]

So on `false` of your `Save Action` you create a collection of query strings with the name of each Field, as it appears in the Form, followed by the User's value.

The code below will loop through all your fields and arrange them into a QueryString with its FieldName and Value;

```cs
        string urlOfForm = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

        var queryString = new StringBuilder("?");
        foreach (AdaptedControlResult field in fields)
        {
            queryString.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", field.FieldName, field.Value));
        }

        urlOfForm = urlOfForm + queryString;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(urlOfForm);
```

Sitecore will then automatically populate the appropriate fields with the values, achieving your requirement.

**EDIT**

I have found that most Exceptions thrown will take the user back to the Form with their values populated. You can then pass in the cause of the failure to write to your CRM. See below for Example

```cs
    if (submitFailed)
    {
        throw new Exception("The email address entered already exists in our System");
    }
```

The complexity then comes in dynamically swapping out the `Save Action Failed Message` to show this `Exception Message`. All posts I find about custom Save Action Message state the only real approach is to redirect via your Custom `Save Action` to a different page showing a different message. Which is not suitable to your requirements.

I have found the pipeline Args you are going to need to patch `FormSubmitFailedArgs` and `SubmitFailedArgs`. The Former will need the following change

```cs
public FormSubmitFailedArgs(ID formID, AdaptedResultList fields, ID actionFailed, Exception ex)
      : base(formID, actionFailed, ex)
        {
            this.Fields = fields;
            this.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
```

and the Latter will need

```cs
public SubmitFailedArgs(ID formID, ID actionFailed, string errorMessage, Exception innerException)
    {
      this.FormID = formID;
      this.ActionFailed = actionFailed;
      this.ErrorMessage = innerException.Message;
      this.InnerException = innerException;
    }
```

**Location and Styling of Submit Message:**

You need to find the FormRender sublayout file, this is defaulted to `website\sitecore modules\Web\Web Forms for Marketers\Control\SitecoreSimpleFormAscx.ascx` inside there you will find a compont called `SubmitSummary` this renders out the submit message so move it to where you require.

Also note it references the `CssClass` `scfSubmitSummary` this is what you will need to target to change the styling of the Message. This Answer is already REALLY long so I won't give a blow by blow how to change the styling of that class, see here for example - http://www.awareweb.com/awareblog/10-1-13-wffmguide

**Pipeline Patching**

I've dug in deeper, in order to use the custom Args we created for using the exception error message you will need to control the Pipeline which ultimately uses those Args, this is the processor `Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipelines.FormSubmit.FormatMessage, Sitecore.Forms.Core` in the `<errorSubmit>` Pipeline.

From my investigation it shouldn't take much effort then its a matter of patching it, you can modify if the `Sitecore.Forms.config` directly or use `patch:instead` from a config file within the `App_Config/Includes` folder - see here for [more info](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/all-about-web-config-include-files-with-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Robbins . I have added further details to my Question.
Please have a look and see if you can help.

Comment: I have updated my code how to get the Url of the Form and how to redirect to it from the Save Action. I'll now work on code to throw an exception to get back to the page and display a dynamic message

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Robbins. Just to mention I am using  Sitecore 7.2 rev. 141226 , Web Forms for Marketers 2.4 rev.140117

Comment: Maybe you can look at using the Form Verifications step,  I haven't dug into it, but you would need to verify against your service before the save step.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a Custom Form Verification Action. You *could* save the data here, although it would be better to verify the data against your API here and then save the data in custom save action, simply since this seems more logical as to how WFFM was meant to function.

```
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Form.Core.Controls.Data;
using Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Custom.WFFM
{
    public class CustomVerificationStep : BaseCheckAction
    {
        public string FailedMessage { get; set; }

        public override void Execute(ID formid, IEnumerable<ControlResult> fields)
        {
            // Call your API
            // You have access to the fields, so you can pass them through as parameters to your if needed
            bool flag = ServiceAPI.ValidateUserData(param1, param2, etc);

            if (!flag)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(this.FailedMessage ?? "There was an error while verifying the data against the service call"));
            }
        }

        public override ActionState QueryState(ActionContext context)
        {
            return ActionState.DisabledSingleCall;
        }
    }
}
```

Create the corresponding Verification Action under `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Form Verification`:

[image: Form Verification Action]

You can change the error message by setting it in the `Parameters` field as  `<FailedMessage>Custom Failed Error Message</FailedMessage>`.

And then add your verification step to your form:

[image: Verification - Add to form]

If you need a different error message per form then you can set the error message to display from the Error Messages tab.

The user will then be returned to the same without any of the save actions being called and the form fields still filled in.